# Get YEAR, MONTH and DAY with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, frontend

I need to get the year, the month and the date from a specific date that's coming from back-end. How can I do that on the front-end controller?

Thanks!

Comment: You write code. Maybe if you showed us what you've tried, preferably in the form of a [mcve], we might be able to help. But this question has been asked and answered many times over, so you'll want to say how your question is different from those.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say the variable name for the date coming from the backend is `D`.

you can do:

```
var date = new Date(D);
var year = date.getFullYear();
var month = date.getMonth();
var day = date.getDay();
```

Comment: And if `D` is a string like `"09/08/2012"`? What should the month be? The result of using your code would depend on the browser, the user's OS, and the regional settings in that OS.

Answer (score 4):

**Example**
**In your HTML** 
  `<div>site design / logo &copy; {{copyright | date:'yyyy'}} Stack Exchange Inc</div>`

**In your AngularJS Controller**

```
    $scope.copyright = new Date();
```

**The output will be**

```
/*site design / logo © 2019 Stack Exchange Inc; */
```

**To Answer your Question**
Controller

```
$scope.dateVariable = new Date();
```

**To get Year in view**

```
{{dateVariable | date:'yyyy'}}
```

**To get Month in view**

```
{{dateVariable | date:'MM'}}
```

**To get Day in view**

```
{{dateVariable | date:'dd'}}
```

For more options such as getting the full date, different ways to display the date, getting the time and getting options on different things/ways to display date items
**The General Syntax is**

```
{{ date | date : format : timezone }}
```

And the output options can be found listed [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp)
or [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Answer (score 0):

In AngularJS (not Angular 2+) you can use the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). This will format a date to a given string based on the format provided. For your situation you can use the following:

```
{{ createdDate | date : ['yyyy'] }} // this will give a 4 digit representation of the year

{{ createdDate | date : ['MMM'] }}  // month in year (January-December)

{{ createdDate | date : ['d'] }} // day in month (1-31)
```

[Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/aF2Q1zaf8i8hYxK0WtCT?p=preview) to demo on Plunker